# unit testing a login view controller in ios related queries

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

i need to perform unit tests for login screen( it has one email textfield, one password textfield and one loginbutton), having a few queries related to it.

what i understand of unit testing of viewcontroller is, i need to make rest of an interacting components (like viewmodels) as mock objects.

So viewcontroller responsibility is only to show/take action what has been sent from mockviewmodel/viewmodel.

In that case for unit testing of login screen, it should only check for, is it taking correct actions based on what has been sent from viewmodels ?

**So actual testing of what kind of error/output generated by different kind of email, password combinations should be done by viewmodel unit tests.**

Is my above understanding of unit testing of loginscreen (viewcontroller) correct ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Unit Testing for your ViewController would be testing that all of your functions/variables (units) are outputting or are equal to an expected value in whatever states the ViewController might be in.

UI Testing for your ViewController would be testing that all UI Components are in the right place, have the right attributes, and are performing the correct actions when tapped (or on other interactions).  This includes testing that segues to other ViewControllers occurs successfully.